# Unable to start activity ComponentInfoandroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: class

Tags: android, android-layout

``time exception I don't know where it is getting error on spec **org.lucsar.dspec** where i deleted that dependency and raw folder which contains spec file from my app. how to resolve this exception.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.sun.suni.design.tabs.SlidingTabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager sPager = null;
    private SlidingTabLayout sTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_nav_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.frag_nav_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
        FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        sPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentmanager));


        sPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        sTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        sTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_line));
        sTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        sTabs.setViewPager(sPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.navigation) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Log.d("sun", "get item is called" + i);
            if (i == 0) {
                fragment = new fragment_a();
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                fragment = new fragment_b();
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                fragment = new fragment_c();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("sun", "get count is called");
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return "Tab 1";
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                return "Tab 2";
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                return "Tab 3";
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

> Log Cat

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sun.suni.design, PID: 1811
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sun.suni.design/com.sun.suni.design.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class org.lucasr.dspec.DesignSpecFrameLayout
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class org.lucasr.dspec.DesignSpecFrameLayout
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.suni.design.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:55)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.suni.design.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.lucasr.dspec.DesignSpecFrameLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sun.suni.design-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.suni.design.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:55) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.suni.design.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lucasr.dspec.DesignSpecFrameLayout
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
12-03 11:37:45.140 1811-1811/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:          ... 36 more



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.sun.suni.design.MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <com.sun.suni.design.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.sun.suni.design.tabs.SlidingTabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_nav_drawer"
        android:name="com.sun.suni.design.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_draw_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Log at your activity_main layout xml file. there you used org.lucasr.dspec.DesignSpecFrameLayout.

Comment: post your activity_main class

Comment: @HeamanthVarma: is `org.lucasr.dspec.` is your app package name?

Comment: @HeamanthVarma: show xml file also where using `org.lucasr.dspec.DesignSpecFrameLayout` string as `android:class` value

Comment: no its not my package name

Comment: Yeah I got it i removed that framelayout from my xml file thank you guys for responding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
     <!-- define new name space for your custom edit text below -->
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/(urpackagename.customcomponentname)"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <!-- Assume that this is your new component. It uses your new attributes -->

            <urpackagename.customcomponentname
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                custom:titleText="Background color"
                custom:valueColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

check whether you have defined in the xml as above